# Swift: using member constant as default value for function parameter

Tags: swift, function-parameter

I have a swift class, in which I am trying to pass a default value for a function parameter:

```
class SuperDuperCoolClass : UIViewController {
   // declared a constant
   let primaryColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 72.0/255.0, green: 86.0/255.0, blue: 114.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

   // compilation error at below line: SuperDuperCoolClass.Type does not have a member named 'primaryColor'
   func configureCheckmarkedBullet(bullet: UIButton, color: UIColor = primaryColor){
       // some cool stuff with bullet and primaryColor
   }
}
```

As stated above, if I try to use constant as default value for function parameter, compiler complains with below error:

```
SuperDuperCoolClass.Type does not have a member named 'primaryColor'
```

but if I assign the RHS value directly like this, it does not complain :-/ :

```
func configureCheckmarkedBullet(bullet: UIButton, color: UIColor = UIColor(red: 72.0/255.0, green: 86.0/255.0, blue: 114.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)) {
        // now I can do some cool stuff
    }
```

Any ideas on how can I silence the above compilation error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define the default value as a *static* property:

```
class SuperDuperCoolClass : UIViewController {

    static let primaryColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 72.0/255.0, green: 86.0/255.0, blue: 114.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    func configureCheckmarkedBullet(bullet: UIButton, color: UIColor = primaryColor){
    }
}
```

The above code compiles with Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3) which added support
for static computed properties. In earlier versions, you can define
a nested `struct` containing the property as a workaround (compare
[Class variables not yet supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015207/class-variables-not-yet-supported)):

```
class SuperDuperCoolClass : UIViewController {

    struct Constants {
        static let primaryColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 72.0/255.0, green: 86.0/255.0, blue: 114.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    func configureCheckmarkedBullet(bullet: UIButton, color: UIColor = Constants.primaryColor){
    }
}
```

Comment: when I tried to declare the constant as static I got this compilation error: static properties are only allowed within structs and enums :-|

Comment: @Miraaj: I have tested the code with Xcode 6.3, which is the current version.

Comment: @Miraaj: Yes. But I have added a workaround for older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Since `primaryColor` is an instance variable it cannot be accessed until an instance is created from this class and since the function is part of the class definition you will get this error as `primaryColor` cannot access at that time.

You can either use MartinR approach or use your approach with the desired color:

```
func configureCheckmarkedBullet(bullet: UIButton, color: UIColor = UIColor(red: 72.0/255.0, green: 86.0/255.0, blue: 114.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)) {
        // now I can do some cool stuff
    }
```