# Instance member as default parameter

Tags: ios, swift, parameters

I am trying to use a property `root` as default parameter in `add` function as below and it is giving me an error:

> Cannot use instance member 'root' as a default parameter
>   .

However, when I am using `root` in a nested function `search` it is working fine.

```
class Trie {
   var root = TrieNode()

   func add(value: String, node: TrieNode? = root) { // error
      var myNode = node
      if myNode == nil {
        myNode = root
      }
      if value.count == 0 {
        node?.setEnd()
        return
      } else if myNode!.keys[String(value.first!)] == nil {
        myNode!.keys[String(value.first!)] = TrieNode()
        return add(value: String(value.dropFirst()), node: myNode!.keys[String(value.first!)])
    } else {
        return add(value: String(value.dropFirst()), node: myNode!.keys[String(value.first!)])
    }
   }


  func allWords() -> [String] {
    var words = [String]()
    func search(node: TrieNode = root, string: String) { // Here it is working fine.
        if node.keys.count != 0 {
            for key in node.keys.keys {
                search(node: node.keys[key]!, string: string+key)
            }
            if node.isEnd {
                words.append(string)
            }
        } else {
            if string.count > 0  {
                words.append(string)
            }
        }
    }

    search(node: self.root, string: "")
    return words
}
}
```

Can someone tell me why I am not able to use a property as the default parameter?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Swift: using member constant as default value for function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29730452/1187415) to me.

Comment: @MartinR: I agree, but I wanted to know how a property can be used as a default parameter in a nested function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift: using member constant as default value for function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730452/swift-using-member-constant-as-default-value-for-function-parameter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is in different context visibility, the arguments context of interface function is *external* in relation to class declaration, so members are not visible, but nested function is declared *inside* class context, as other function body, so members are visible.

So the solution might be static, as already proposed, but it might have drawbacks (eg. for reference default members), so I recommend to use it only for constants.

The other possible solutions is below

```
func add(value: String, node: TrieNode?) { // no error
    func _add(value: String, node: TrieNode? = root) { // in-context
        var myNode = node
        if myNode == nil {
            myNode = root
        }
        if value.count == 0 {
            node?.setEnd()
            return
        } else if myNode!.keys[String(value.first!)] == nil {
            myNode!.keys[String(value.first!)] = TrieNode()
            return add(value: String(value.dropFirst()), node: myNode!.keys[String(value.first!)])
        } else {
            return add(value: String(value.dropFirst()), node: myNode!.keys[String(value.first!)])
        }
    }
    _add(value: value, node: node)
}
```

Comment: _the arguments context of interface function is external_ why do you say it's external? If this was a private property then I would have agreed, but root is a visible/public property. Why can't it get processed just like a function gets processed?

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have explained *why* you can't do it.

I suggest that the simplest way to achieve what you want is via the *nil coalescing operator*

```
func add(value: String, node: TrieNode? = nil) { // error
  var myNode = node ?? root

  guard let key = value.first, keyStr = String(key) else {
      myNode.setEnd()
      return
  }

  let updateNode = myNode.keys[keyStr, default: TrieNode()]
  return add(value: String(value.dropFirst(), node: updateNode)
 }
```

Comment: Can be `let myNode`

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a static variable as suggested in the comments and then update the value of it when `root` changes

```
class Trie {
    static var defaultNode = TrieNode()

    var root = TrieNode() {
        didSet {
            Trie.defaultNode = root
        }
    }

func add(value: String, node: TrieNode? = Trie.defaultNode) {
```

The main issue with this is that `defaultNode` would be the same for all instances of Trie and also that all instances can change it, of course you can `let` declare  it so that it is constant but then what is the point of having it at all (although I don't see that you ever change `root`?).

Another option is to skip the default value in the function declaration and instead have it inside the function

```
class Trie {
    var root = TrieNode()

    func add(value: String, node: TrieNode?) { 
        let myNode = node ?? root
        if value.count == 0 {
            myNode.setEnd()
            return
        }
        //... rest of code
    }
```