# KEEP keyboard ON when UIAlertcontroller is presented in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uialertcontroller, presentviewcontroller

When the alert pops up the keyboard is dismissed. I have looked everywhere but did not find solutions to keep the keyboard visible. When alert is presented the textfield seems to resign first responder automatically as the alert is presented modally. How is it possible to keep the keyboard behind this alert which means the textfield still editing even if no interaction will be possible ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This solution works for me:

```
let rootViewController: UIViewController = 
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.lastObject.rootViewController!!
rootViewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

---

*edit by @galambalazs:* The reason it works is because:

You can grab the window with the current highest window level and present your *View Controller* inside that *Window* (making it the top *View Controller* in the top *Window*).

> [**UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/windows)
>   The windows in the array are ordered from back to front by window level;
>   thus, the last window in the array is on top of all other app windows.

Also you might want to set the tintColor of that window so that it matches your apps global tintColor.

```
UIWindow *topWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject;
// we inherit the main window's tintColor because topWindow may not have the same
topWindow.tintColor = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.tintColor;
```

Comment: It looks like this is using the window the status bar is in to present the alert controller, right?

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. The second window in `UIAppplication.sharedApplication().windows` is a UITextEffectsWindow.

Comment: After more research, I discovered that UITextEffectsWindow is where the keyboard view (or UIViewController inputAccessoryView) is located. So this second window will only exist if the keyboard has been displayed. http://www.fantageek.com/1317/uiwindow-in-ios/

Comment: So that worked for me. Although the background turns black and that is not good if you are using an effect as background (using the actual view controller's view). Also the transition is not good (because replaces the actual view with a black background). Still looking for better solution...

Comment: I think you should use UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.lastObject.rootViewController, then the code will work whether keyboard show or hide.

Comment: Is there another way other than accessing the internal window hierarchy?

Comment: Thanks. The solution only worked well in iOS 8, it does not work on iOS 9 though. Also Note in the answer, there is an extra `!` at the end, which is not needed. with Swift 2.1

Comment: @smoothdvd 's solution works well for iOS 9 and 8. Although in iOS 8, I got some crashes sometimes. Looking into the issue.

Comment: should `lastObject` be replaced by `last`?

Comment: I am facing same problem when i do
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false , and true
Any advice about it.

Answer (score 3):

> For Swift 3 and iOS11

```
if let alertWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.last, alertWindow.windowLevel == 10000001.0 // If keyboard is open
  { // Make sure keyboard is open
    alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
  else
  {
    viewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```