# How to input text into the first responder programatically in jailbroken iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, jailbreak, tweak

In my app, I need to input specified text into the first responder, I have no idea about that, I think first I should get the focused control, which may be `UITextField`, `UITextView` or something else defined by the developers.But how can I get the focused controls?Particularly I want to do that in a tweak for jailbroken iPhone.
Or maybe my train of thought is totally wrong, maybe I should send some `IOHIDEvents` to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by cursor focused? Do you want to get the first responder?

Comment: Yes, I mean the first responder.

Comment: Do you want to get the first responder only inside your app, or in all apps?

Comment: I want to get the first responder in all apps.

Comment: Okay, Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/get-the-current-first-responder-without-using-a-private-api)? I'm not sure it will work for all apps, but it uses a private API (which you can use without a problem)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try @JakobEgger 's answer at that page, I think it's fishier.

Comment: Please tell me if it worked for you.

Comment: I've tried, the answer are not applicable.It extends `UIResponder`, but it have to be imported to every place to make it work, but that's not practical.

Comment: Have you tried the code in the question itself? I thought this one might work for you because it uses private API

Comment: I haven't tried it, but does `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] performSelector:@selector(firstResponder)]` only get the first responder of the application in which the programing is running? My tweak will run in `SpringBoard`, but I want to get the first responder of all the applications these are at the front most.

Comment: Maybe you can run some code whenever an application is launched by the user, and save its `UIApplication` object?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I'll try it, or maybe injecting some functions into `firstResponder` method of the `UIApplication` will work.

Comment: What kind of code would you inject into `firstResponder` method? You wouldn't want to prevent from other applications to get their own first responder.

Comment: May inject some codes can register the current first responder to a  variable I can access.