# Is it possible to get textfield assosiated with a keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uikit

In my view controller I'm subscribed to `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

so in my `keyboardWillShow:` method I'm able to retrieve some info about the keyboard from the notification. But what I want is to get the reference to the actual text field which brings the keyboard up. I couldn't find how to do that in google and I suspect it might be impossible, but someone might know. If it is indeed impossible then I would like to know if there's a possibility to make it reverse way - to get the info about the keyboard by having the reference to the text field. Thanks

Comment: You should use `UITextField delegate` function `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` this delegate function will get call when your keyboard appears, and save the UITextField reference from this function?

Comment: Yes, I know that of course, but it is not convenient for me in current architecture. I'm going to use that approach as a last resort if i don't find anything else

Comment: I wish I could add +2 to @iphonic: only `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` works. The `keyboardWillShow ` is flaky, and will not work with hardware keyboards (bluetooth, common on iPad)

Comment: @iphonic is 100% correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me **emphasize** that @iphonic comment is the *right way to go.*

> You should use `UITextField` delegate function `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`

Anything short of that is a kludge: `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` assumes the software keyboard will show up, with is a very dangerous assumption and is **likely to fail** in all sorts of situations, starting with but not limited to Bluetooth keyboards. *Try cmd-K in Simulator.*

Here is aforementioned kludge, inspired by [Get the current first responder without using a private API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/)

```
func keyboardWillShow() {
    let firstResponder = self.findFirstResponder(inView: self.view)
    println("keyboardWillShow for \(firstResponder)")
}

func findFirstResponder(inView view: UIView) -> UIView? {
    for subView in view.subviews as! [UIView] {
        if subView.isFirstResponder() {
            return subView
        }

        if let recursiveSubView = self.findFirstResponder(inView: subView) {
            return recursiveSubView
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is one manual way

```
if ([firstName isFirstResponder]) {
    // caused due to firstName
} else if ([lastName isFirstResponder]) {
    // caused due to lastName
}
```

Swift

```
if firstName.isFirstResponder { // caused due to firstName } 
else
if lastName.isFirstResponder { // caused due to lastName }
```

Comment: Definitely less code if you know your responders ahead of time, as in not in dynamic cells for example.

Comment: Add swift 3 support:

            if firstName.isFirstResponder {
 // caused due to firstName
            } else if lastName.isFirstResponder {
 // caused due to lastName
            }

Answer (score 3):

The easiest (and almost only) way to do this happens to also be the **best** way (as [@iphonic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/790842/iphonic) mentioned)

> Implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` delegate method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:textField`

This method will be called **before any other event** (including any keyboard notifications)

> Store the `UITextField` that received this delegate call to be referenced when determining which field triggered this event.

---

What I also recommend doing is, if you are looking to determine which keyboard fired the current keyboard appearance, **within** this delegate method simply register for receiving keyboard notifications.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    return YES;

}
```

This way, you can be certain that when `keyboardWillShow:` is called, it was in fact triggered from this specific text field.

Of course, to make sure you keep track of your text fields correctly, stop listening when the text field stops editing.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is much better way to do this via did begin editing notifications of `UITextField` and `UITextView`:

`UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification`

and

`UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification`

```
- (void)startListeningForKeyboardNotification {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(responderDidBeginEditing:) name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(responderDidBeginEditing:) name:UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)responderDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([notification.object isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = notification.object;
        // Do something with text field
    } else if ([notification.object isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        UITextView *textView = notification.object;
        // Do something with text view
    }
}
```