# Send backspace key event to active text field

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking to send a backspace to my active UITextField once I shake my phone.

I'm catching the shake event fine but can't figure out how to send a backspace character to the first responder (active control).

Anyone able to help?

Comment: What do you need help with? Determining the current first responder and whether it is a `UITextField` or how to call the `deleteBackward` method on the `UITextField`?

Comment: I'm basically trying to figure out how to call `deleteBackward` (and later also `insertText`) on whatever active responder I might have when I shake the device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/get-the-current-first-responder-without-using-a-private-api

Comment: I entered up having to iterate subviews of the first view found being `firstResponder` .. then I would find the first subview being a `isFirstResponder` as well as a subview confirming to `UIKeyInput` using `confirmsToProtocol(@protocol(UIKeyInput)`. Finally I could typecast to `id<UIKeyInput>` and perform my `insertText` and `deleteBackward` methods. Urgh :)

Answer (score -2):

You have to do it this way

if(_shakes){

```
NSString *strrr = _textField.text;

NSString *modStr = [strrr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [strrr length]-1)];

NSLog(@"Print %@",modStr);

_textField.text = modStr;
```

}