# Hide keyboard in iOS for any view?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, navigation, keyboard, mmdrawercontroller

There are similar questions but they are all about cases when they know which view is editing.

In my case I have a local notification and I want to hide keyboard when app becomes active with it.

In the same time I have a complex navigation which involves `MMDrawerController` and modal views. So I can't just take topmost view controller and iterate its subviews.

So could you explain how to hide keyboard if I don't know the view currently viewing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a category to `UIResponder`:
[Get the current first responder without using a private API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21330810/6279975)

```
static __weak id currentFirstResponder;

@implementation UIResponder (FirstResponder)

+(id)currentFirstResponder {
    currentFirstResponder = nil;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(findFirstResponder:) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
    return currentFirstResponder;
}

-(void)findFirstResponder:(id)sender {
    currentFirstResponder = self;
}

+(void)hideKeyboard {
    id firstResponder = [UIResponder currentFirstResponder];
    if([firstResponder respondsToSelector:@selector(endEditing:)]) {
        [firstResponder endEditing:YES];
    }
}

@end
```

Import the category and do below in your action to hide keyboard:

```
if([[UIResponder currentFirstResponder] respondsToSelector:@selector(endEditing:)]) {
    [[UIResponder currentFirstResponder] endEditing:YES];
}
```

By this solution, you do not need to know the view currently viewing. Just get the current first responder and call `endEdition:`. For when editable view become editing, it will become first responder.

**EDIT:**

With Vyachaslav Gerchicov's suggestion, I add `hideKeyboard` method in the category. And just call `[UIResponder hideKeyboard];`.

Comment: What about to fix this answer a little? You could add `+ (void)hideKeyboard` method inside this category.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate throught views u want to hide keyboard for and check `view.isFirstResponder` if its true then simply do `view.resignFirstResponder`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get Center Panel of your DrawerViewController and add below code from didReceiveRemoteNotification methods.

```
[drawerController.centerViewController.view resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: The same as "self.view" - what if `centerViewController` hasn't text field? In my case it even contains of navigation controllers