# How to determine which textfield has focus in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have three textfields with `1,2,3` tags respectively. After pressing a button how do I get the textfield which has focus on.

For instance, I am tying in textfield tag 1 and then press a button, how do I determine if I am on textfield tag 1

Comment: Swift answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27140764/3151675

Comment: No, it is not possible duplicate. I'm just trying to use textfields not having issues over API

Comment: Please read the duplicate I’ve provided. It addresses the same issue you’re facing.

Comment: Just check which textfield is the first responder and you are done. And this is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: If you are "pressing a button", wouldn't *that* button have the focus? Maybe if you provide some code (and maybe a tag on if it's macOS or iOS) it would clarify things. "Focus" is generally not an iOS term - and in macOS while you "press" a button the focus is on the button pressed. So if you are actually asking asking which textfield is the first responder, well, yes this *is* a duplicate.

Comment: Hi @Alex, what have you tried so far?  Can you include a code snippet?

Comment: Lack of relevant tags